# Autosave loading problem with my ETS2 profile after removing mod

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

When I remove a mod and press "continue game", my game leads me to the log of autosaves, as normal. When I press "load", my game shows me a list of the disabled mods. Usually, when I press "continue", my game would have just loaded until I were fully logged in on my account (if you know what I mean), but now, instead of leading me to my site, where I can see my truck and I have the option to select drive, the game just automatically shows me the site of all my autosaves again and if I do try to do the same again from the new loaded log of autosaves it just load and show me the same log of autosaves. What I am saying is my autosaves prevents me from reaching my account. But if I put in the mods I just removed it works fine! I don't wont to play whit snow all the time and I don't want to delete my account either. Picture of what it looks like and note yourself that I don't have that background for normal.

[image]

Comment: From my experience, if you get a mod that can't be played without (as it seems you have), your only recourse is to either start over, or load a saved game from before introducing the mod.

I've encountered a few mod issues and fortunately had save games that I had to take a hit to reload, but nowadays, I'll load mods I think I may want to remove and then try to reload saved games after doing so, just to ensure I won't be screwed.